# How to configure PPPoE in ubuntu under wired connection not DSL

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, ethernet, pppoe

I have ISP who gave me username, password, and authentication type for PPoE and provide ethernet cable wire home to home for accessing internet. Now my problem is how to configure it for wired connection. I must tell you my ISP is not DSL or ADSL but ethernet as I mentioned earlier, so when i look for PPPoE setting under wired connection it isn't there but I can find that option under DSL which ask for username and password and authentication type for identifying user.

Like in windows  under `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center` when we choose the option of `Set up a new connection or network` then the  option of

```
Broadband(PPPoE)
Connect using DSL or cable that requires a user name and password
```

and ther we go done in window but where does this option comes in `UBUNTU`.

Please help me out, what am I should I do because i tried with all the inputs under DSL also and when I connect the link never establishes so please help. It would really be appreciative.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I am in same problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I got the correct answer, and in retrospect it may look silly why didn't I tried that.

Answer to above problem is :

1. Go to `Network Connection`  by clicking window button(or super which ever works) search for `Network Connection` open it.
2. Look for `DSL` tab at top right and click it. Choose the option add then again under `DSL` fill in the required detail about username and password provided by your ISP/ Before you do it please ask your ISP to reset the MAC filtering or ask him to add the one you are configuring(in my case I asked them to reset but they did not do it first time so one again when I tried on ubuntu I asked them to reset and this time it worked ).

Cheers!!! P:)